# CakePHP: Model that belongs to multiple others, one at a time

Tags: database-design, cakephp, polymorphism

I have three tables: "users", "courses" and "documents". I would like to upload documents to users as well as to courses, so I would need two belongsTo-relations for the Document model. Some belong to one model, some to the other.

Is there a simple solution to construct these relations?

How could I set up the "add"-actions?

I know I could set up two join tables and use HABTM, but that doesn't feel right. A document belongs only to *one* other item. Besides, I want to be able to extend the relations to more models if neccessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called polymorphism. Basically, you're not associating a model with a fixed other model through a single `other_model_id` field, but you keep track of two fields: `other_model_class` and `other_model_foreign_key`. That way you can associate a `Document` with `class: User, id: 42` in one case and `class: Course, id: 42` in another. There's a [Behavior in the Bakery](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/polymorphic-behavior), which should be a good place to start.

Comment: +1 This is a powerful behavior that works great. I've used it with great success on a couple of projects.

Comment: See this related question for CakePHP 2 [Polymorphic associations in CakePHP2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835298/polymorphic-associations-in-cakephp2)